# how to place overlapped images either on canvas or layout

Tags: android

My requirment is there will be a india map and some imageview or buttons will be there on top of that map.when i drag and drop the button on that top of map color of some areas has to change ..

Please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If u dont want drag and drop option u can place some invisible imageviews on the top when ever user press the top buttons u can make them visible.
Like suppose if want to change the are of andra pradesh .place red color andhra pradesh on the top of white andrha pradesh and when ever u click top button make its status as  visible.